# How to find radius of a circle when equations of parallel tangents are given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, circles

> Equations of two parallel tangents to a circle are
>   $2x-4y-9=0$ and $6x-12y+7=0$. How do I find the radius of the circle?

I have tried many methods, but still I  could not find the radius.
I know that the distance between two parallel tangents is equal to the diameter, but none of the contact point are given.

If I assume the centre to be $(a,b)$ and radius to be $r$ then when I apply the perpendicular distance of a line from a point I get two equations but I have three unknowns, so I cannot solve....any help will be appreciated

Comment: Neither the points of contact nor the centre of the circle is needed. Hint: Start by choosing a point on one of the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The distance between two parallel lines, $y=mx + c_1$ and $y=mx+c_2$ is 
$$d = \frac{|c_1-c_2|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1. Consider the line through the origin perpendicular to the tangents that is $y=-2x$
2. Determine the intersections points P and Q between this perpendicular line and the tangents
3. Then $2R=PQ$

Answer (score 1):

You need the distance between the two lines, which is the diameter. You should know how to compute the distance between a point and a line. Take an arbitrary (convenient) point on the most complicated looking line and find the distance from that point to the other line. Alternatively "draw a diagram" and "do the geometry (pythagoras)" - diagrams are surprisingly useful for this kind of problem..

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

- normalize the coefficients of $x,y$, i.e. find the unitary normal vector to the two lines
  which thus shall be the same, and (if not) better to take with the same orientation
  $$
  {\bf n} = {1 \over {\sqrt {20} }}\left( {2, - 4} \right) = {1 \over {\sqrt {180} }}\left( {6, - 12} \right) = {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}\left( {1, - 2} \right)
  $$
- rewrite the equations accordingly
  $$
  {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}x - {2 \over {\sqrt 5 }}y = {9 \over {2\sqrt 5 }}\quad \quad {1 \over {\sqrt 5 }}x - {2 \over {\sqrt 5 }}y =  - {7 \over {6\sqrt 5 }}
  $$
- the above tells you that the two lines are at distance from the origin, measured in the orientation of $\bf n$, of
  $ {9 \over {2\sqrt 5 }}$ and $ - {7 \over {6\sqrt 5 }}$, i.e. at ${17 \over {3\sqrt 5 }}$ from each other.

Then it is easy to write the equation of the middle line, and to put your circle with the center over that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Given equations of the parallel lines

\begin{align}
y&=\tfrac12\,x-\tfrac9{4}
,\\
y&=\tfrac12\,x+\tfrac7{12}
,
\end{align}

we can construct a triangle $ABC$
with two distinct points on one line 
and the third point on another line,
for example as

\begin{align} 
A&=(0,-\tfrac94),\quad
B=(\tfrac92,0),\quad
C=(0,\tfrac7{12})
.
\end{align}

For this triangle we can find that
\begin{align} 
|AB|&=\sqrt{(B_x-A_x)^2+(B_y-A_y)^2}
=\tfrac{9\sqrt5}4
\end{align}

and the area can be found as
\begin{align} 
S_{\triangle ABC}
&=
\tfrac12((B_x-A_x)(C_y-A_y)
-(B_y-A_y)(C_x-A_x))
=\tfrac{51}8
.
\end{align}

Given that, we can find the height $|CD|$ of $\triangle ABD$
as
\begin{align}
|CD|&=\frac{2S_{\triangle ABC}}{|AB|}
=\frac{17\sqrt5}{15}
\end{align}
and the radius of the circle is then
\begin{align}
R&=\tfrac12|CD|=\frac{17\sqrt5}{30}
\approx 1.2671
.
\end{align}

Comment: I know this is a relatively old answer, but if you do remember, I'd love to know what tool do you use to make images like that?

Comment: @Rook: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/),
but it's deeply integrated with [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote),
and is part of [TeXLive distribution](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).